# Adding filter or transparent .png over a user submitted background image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, filter

Looking for assistance in modifying a WordPress page template that allows users to submit a listing/post of a venue and include a image that is used as a background image. The issue is that when a user submits an image using the custom field called "listing_banner", depending on the background image submitted with the listing by the user, the image submitted may make it difficult to read the white text in from of the background image. Here is a link to a sample listing: http://www.myvipclubs.com/test/city/detroit/listing/v-at-mgm-grand-detroit/

Looking for assistance to add one of the following to the existing code:

1. an additional div tag that refers to the Wordpress custom css file that includes a css element that points to a transparent image (.png) that can be placed in front of the listing_banner image when a user submits the background image (http://www.myvipclubs.com/test/submit-listing/). 
   Issue: When using div class .full_detail_overlay_image, the transparent image is over the listing_banner image and the text. Only want the image to be darker, not the text. Assuming need to have a class where it clears the css style and does not affect the text.
2. Modify the existing css. style for the background image (.full_width_detail) that includes a filter to change any image submitted by the user.

Using either possible solution looking for someone to assist in getting the right code using either css or a transparent image as an overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an extra div element, you can do this by making use of a before or after pseudo element.

I've very quickly put together an example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/916caLj7/) using the css below.

```
.full_width_detail:before {
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16100000/Cute-Kitten-kittens-16122946-1280-800.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
    padding: 50px;
}
.full_width_detail:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    z-index: 1
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

You'll need to make sure that your div element is relatively positioned and that the pseudo element .full_width_detail:before is absolutely positioned and given a z-index higher than that of the div so that it sits above.

In this example I've used an rgba background for the :before element. The .15 value can of course be changed to make the tint more opaque should you wish. If you really must you can use a transparent png instead of the rgba background, but personally I like to use rgba with a fall back if I need to support older browsers.

The content of the div in this case the text needs to be relatively positioned and have a z-index higher than .full_width_detail:before.

Comment: Your example gave us exactly what we needed. The z-index and the pseudo element .full_width_detail:before was definitely the missing pieces to the puzzle. Thanks for helping us out.